# data.table version of ldply

Tags: r, data.table

It is equivalent to 'ldply' for 'data.frame':
`lapply` a function to a list(say 'mylist') and then 'rbindlist' to the list of 'data.table's (which automatically appends the 'names(mylist)' as ID column).

I know it is trivial to write such convenient wrapper, but just wondering if it is something 'data.table' package already provides?

Comment: `rbindlist` has an option `idcol=TRUE` (esp in the devel version of data.table).  Not sure whether that is what you meant

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand the question.  Since a data.table is "an enhanced version of data.frames", in many cases you *could* treat it as a data.frame.  Data.table has a special symbol ".SD" that lets you work with subsets of the original data.  Between ".SD" and the ":=" operator, I think you will find your answer.  Here are a few resources:

See section **"e) Multiple columns in j - .SD"** in the following documentation:
https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro-vignette.html

See section **"b) The := operator"** in the following documentation:
https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html

Quoting from the documentation:

> To compute on (multiple) columns, we can then simply use the base R
>   function lapply().

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=ID]
#    ID   a    b    c
# 1:  b 2.0  8.0 14.0
# 2:  a 4.5 10.5 16.5
# 3:  c 6.0 12.0 18.0
```

Please provide a reproducible example of what you are trying to accomplish if this is not what you meant.

PS:  I found this tutorial very helpful: 
https://www.datacamp.com/courses/data-table-data-manipulation-r-tutorial

Comment: Your first link is accessible by typing `vignette("datatable-intro")`. Best to keep external links to a minimum. Also, much of what you're writing is comment material (asking for clarification or an example, directing them to a helpful link).